# Evaluate only the latest window for event time based sliding windows

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I would like to process events in EvenTime using sliding windows. The sliding interval is 24 hours and increment is 30 minutes. The problem is that below code is producing 48 calculations for each event. In our case events are coming in order so we need only the latest window to be evaluated.

Thanks,

Dejan

```
public static void processEventsa(
        DataStream<Tuple2<String, MyEvent>> events) throws Exception {

    events.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new MyWatermark()).
            keyBy(0).
            timeWindow(Time.hours(windowSizeHour), Time.seconds(windowSlideSeconds)).
            apply(new WindowFunction<Tuple2<String, MyEvent>, Tuple2<String, MyEvent>, Tuple, TimeWindow>() {
                @Override
                public void apply(Tuple key, TimeWindow window, Iterable<Tuple2<String, MyEvent>> input,
                                          Collector<Tuple2<String, MyEvent>> out) throws Exception {

                    for (Tuple2<String, MyEvent> record : input) {



                    }
                }
            });
}

public class MyWatermark implements
        AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks<Tuple2<String, MyEvent>> {

    @Override
    public long extractTimestamp(Tuple2<String, MyEvent> event, long previousElementTimestamp) {
        return event.f1.eventTime;
    }

    @Override
    public Watermark checkAndGetNextWatermark(Tuple2<String, MyEvent> event, long previousElementTimestamp) {
        return new Watermark(event.f1.eventTime);
    }
}

final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in watermark. AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks should be used

```
public class MyWatermark implements
        AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<Tuple2<String, MyEvent>> {

    private final long maxTimeLag = 5000;

    @Override
    public long extractTimestamp(Tuple2<String, MyEvent> event, long previousElementTimestamp) {
        try {
            return event.f1.eventTime;
        }
        catch(NullPointerException ex) {}

        return System.currentTimeMillis() - maxTimeLag;
    }

    @Override
    public Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
        return new Watermark(System.currentTimeMillis() - maxTimeLag);
    }
}
```